# Go programing language please help me set up eclipse or vim or text editor

Tags: eclipse, go

I am starting to learn go programing language. I have installed zeus, and eclipse/goclipse. (I like text editor, however i did not find any instructions to plug in with go and compile it). 
Now, on eclipse I ran a basic `hello world` and I am getting this:
`"Executable source files must be in the 'cmd' folder"`

1. `GOROOT` set on `c:\Go\`
2. `GOOS` set on `windows`,
3. `GOARCH` set on `386` (I forgot my system, I have windows 32bit)
4. `Go` tool path (go) set on auto `"c:\go\bin\go.exe"`
5. Go formatter path set on auto
6. (gofmt)auto `"c:\go\bin\gofmt.exe"`
7. and Go documentor path (godoc) set on auto "c:\go\bin\godoc.exe"
8. finally the GOPATH is empty.

I was following instructions on here http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/wiki/InstallationInstructions and here http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/wiki/GettingStarted.

Now, on the second link says cmd on the explorer window, there is no "cmd" there is bin, pkg, and src. If you can see why i have the error code, i appreciated a million and thank you veeery much in advance. If anyone can help me set up either vim, or text editor to use with go i can go that route as well. Also, i forgot one more thing, like Socrates says, i know nothing hehe so if you could tell me step at a time to fix as i am proud to be noob.
Thanks for reading and sorry about the long text because i wanted to give as much detail as possible.
Mar,
Thanks, again.

Comment: What folder were your executable files in?

Comment: jdi i thought i did clear it enough but when asked, it crumbled all together like garbage as you said. Chris, it is on src folder from the explore window

Comment: Did you try moving the executable files from the src folder to the cmd folder (creating it if necessary)?

Comment: Chris, there is no 'cmd' folder. There is bin, pkg, and src folders. i tried to open src from where i saved 'go' and it is empty. This is dumb question but how do i create if necessary? Also, when i explore the project name it goes like this, bin, pkg, src "hello.go" then GOROOT. When open GOROOT there are alot of folders.

Comment: @ChrisGerken Thanks for helping, i cant wait to start coding, spent like whole day yesterday and today to figure it out and best i came up with to set the variable and everything else set automatically. Yet still stuck.

Comment: Those directions are outdated. You should not need a `cmd` folder any more as that was old Go structure. All that matters is that you point your GOPATH as the root location containing a `src`, `pkg` and optionally a `bin`. Thats for GO 1.x in general. Not sure about what GoClipse might need

Comment: @jdi I realized that when it was not executing the simple task. I am stomped and don't really know what to do to get this code compile succesfully.

Comment: Have you tried simply compiling from the command line, before adding an IDE's build tools into the mix?

Comment: @jdi, no i did not run from command line. I wrote a simpe hello.go on note++ but i honestly do not know how to run it on command line. I am guessing, command promt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the project state of Goclipse really is, since I don't use it, but I would suggest first and foremost trying the basics of compiling from the command prompt. This will ensure you actually have it working. The instructions given for Goclipse seem old as `cmd` is not required anymore. That may just be something internal for the project structure in Eclipse+Goclipse.

*Disclaimer: I work in OSX/Linux. This advise for windows is off the top of my head*

If you have already set your system environment variables to the paths you mentioned, then from the command prompt, you should successfully be able to run the `go` command.

If you `cd` in the location of your `hello.go` test file, you should then be able to run:
`go build hello.go`, and have a resulting `hello` executable in the same location. That is the first step to building a single file.

`GOPATH` allows you to set a location for which Go should search to find packages. This location should have underneath it a `src` directory, and a `pkg` directory. Your project go will live under `src`, and `pkg` is where packages get installed. Having a `bin` is optional since you can direct the executables to whatever location you want with `GOBIN` or the `-o` flag of running `go build -o /path/to/bin/hello hello.go`

A generic GOPATH structure might look like this:

```
projects/
  src/
    hello/
      hello.go
  pkg/
```

You would then be able to set `GOPATH=/path/to/projects` and could build from any location via:
`go build -o /path/to/bin/hello hello`

Another alternative to Eclipse is using [SublimeText2](http://www.sublimetext.com/), which I have found to be excellent, and it is cross-platform just like Eclipse. It also has a package manager to install plugins, and there is a great Go plugin called [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime)

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/code.html for how to write go code

Comment: @jdi you are the man thank you so much. I actually took the route with SublimeText2, very awesome. I also installed GoSublime, and set the user folder with GoSublime/Sublime.settings. Here comes the head scratching, im sorry to bother you, just for heads up, but how should i run the basic code? I mean, i will build obviously, but how should i compile it? There is no compile, or run or nothing on this Sublime text2. If you give me directions to do that then im ready to just be by the computer all the time learning 'Go'. I am set up finally, thank you both. This is the last step, whew! Close.

Comment: The build command brings up a command entry box already filled with the go command. You would be able to just do: "go build". That will compile. Either that or the more explicit: "go build hello" or whatever your project is. It will compile. SublimeText is expandable so you can create your own hot keys and per project settings to make it even easier.

Comment: @jdi Thank you so much. I have done everything by setting up first before i can get to the "go build" except the GoImport. I followed your instruction and good find on Sublime. And for those step by Step instruction here. http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/setting-up-a-ide-to-play-with-go-on-windows/ However, i am on the step to install Git and i downloaded the file did not extracted it yet because i can not find this folder %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\GoImport I appreciated the follow up. After this i am all set up.

Comment: `%APPDATA%` is a windows environment variable that probably expands to: `C:\Users\YOU\AppData`

Comment: @jdi Ok, i finally found it by c:\Users\Me\AppData by clicking on the address bar then clicking on twice and typing \AppData. Since that is done, here is another question i don't understand. I have this C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\New Folder instead of this C:\Users\Me\AppData\Sublime text 2\Packages is that ok? Also, the new folder says actually "New Folder" where i am about to extract to, that is ok as well correct? This is my last step, i am ready to go. Thanks again, you don't understand how much i appreciate the help. I also hpe it helps someone else as well.

Comment: "New Folder" is probably because you created a new folder and didnt name it anything. I am sure it needs to be named something proper like the package name you are installing

Comment: @jdi I named GoImport. The world could end up right now and i would not leave this computer till i finish setting Go up with Sublime Text 2. Anyway, i am following this install through cmd and im typing the folder name it does not accept. Here is what im trying to do, "For Windows:Open a cmd, go to %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages and type..." Did not get this task accomplished....help. This is next, "git clone git://github.com/cthackers/SublimeGoBuild.git So close man,  so close, finger tips close to start coding....

Comment: Well thanks for your help @jdi. Thisquestion is getting longer. I have to run to school. I found the file on cmd by clicking shift+right clicking on the folder and from the pull down window clicking on 'command here" and i typed gi clocne git:// etc etc but it does not recognize it. I will figure it out but i don't want to keep making this post longer and longer. Many thanks.